# gitlab CI different SSL keys for different server deployments, how?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab-ci.yml that has this content:

```
before_script:
    # Setup SSH deploy keys
    - which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install -qq openssh-client )
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - bash -c 'ssh-add <(echo "$KEY1")'
    - bash -c 'ssh-add <(echo "$KEY2")'
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - ssh-keyscan ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xx1.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - ssh-keyscan ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx2.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

// more stuff that tests the code

staging:
    type: deploy
    script:
        - shell/deploy_s_staging_ci.sh
    only:
        - tags
            - s_staging
```

My environment has the $KEY1 and $KEY2 stored.

The last line of my **local** deployment shell script is like this:

```
scp -v -i "~/.ssh/example.pem" s_etl_deploy.tgz  \
ec2-user@ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user/etl/
```

How is this altered to pick up a particular SSL Key, lets say KEY1, in the gitlb CI docker runner, to use that in the scp command?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably make it possible to select between both keys.
For example, using variables permit to achieve that goal.

```
.use_ssh_key:
  before_script:
    # Setup SSH deploy keys
    - which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install -qq openssh-client )
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - bash -c 'ssh-add <(echo "$KEY_TO_USE")'
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - ssh-keyscan ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xx1.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - ssh-keyscan ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx2.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

// more stuff that tests the code

staging:
  extends: .use_ssh_key
  variables:
    KEY_TO_USE: $KEY1
  type: deploy
  script:
    - shell/deploy_s_staging_ci.sh
  only:
    - tags
        - s_staging
```

Then you can just extend that configuration, and define the KEY_TO_USE depending on your job.